# When does using floating point operations to calculate ceiling-integer-log2 fail?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, rounding-error

I'm curious what the first input is which differentiates these two functions:

```py
from math import *

def ilog2_ceil_alt(i: int) -> int:
    # DO NOT USE THIS FUNCTION IT'S WRONG
    return ceil(log2(i))

def ilog2_ceil(i: int) -> int:
    # Correct
    if i <= 0:
        raise ValueError("math domain error")
    return (i-1).bit_length()

...
```

Obviously, the first one is going to fail for some inputs due to rounding/truncation errors when cramming (the log of) an unlimited-sized integer through a finite `double` in the pipeline— however, I tried running this test code for a few minutes, and it didn't *find* a problem:

```
...

def test(i):
    if ilog2_ceil(i) != ilog2_ceil_alt(i):
        return i

def main(start=1):
    import multiprocessing, itertools
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    it = p.imap_unordered(test, itertools.count(start), 100)
    return next(i for i in it if i is not None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = main()
    print("Failing case:", i)
```

I tried testing assorted large values like `2**32` and `2**64 + 9999`, but it didn't fail on these.

What is the smallest (positive) integer for which the "alt" function fails?

Comment: It will almost certainly be a power of 2, +/-1.

Comment: On my machine `ilog2_ceil_alt(2**49+1)` fails (it returns 49, but should return 50)

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, because log2(2^n + 1) = n + log2(1 + 2^(−n)) ≈ n + 0.43·2^(−n), so that you will have rounding issues as soon as n gets about p − log2(p). Or you should use rounding toward +∞ when supported by the C library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A first issue with `ceil(log2(i))` is that the integer `i` will first be converted to the floating-point type toward 0 (this is the wrong direction!), here with a 53-bit precision. For instance, if `i` is 2<sup>53</sup> + 1, it will be converted to 2<sup>53</sup>, and you'll get 53 instead of 54.

But another problem may occur even with smaller values: The values to consider are those that are slightly larger than a power of 2, say 2<sup>n</sup> + k with a small integer k > 0, because the log2 may round to the integer n (even if log2 is correctly rounded) while you would want a FP number slightly larger than n at this point. Thus this will give `ceil(n)`, i.e. n instead of n+1.

Now, let's consider the worst case for k, i.e. k = 1. Let p denote the precision (on your example, p = 53 for the double precision, but let's generalize). One has log2(2<sup>n</sup> + 1) = n + log2(1 + 2<sup>−n</sup>) ≈ n + 0.43·2<sup>−n</sup>. If the representation of n needs exactly q bits, then the ulp will be 2<sup>q−p</sup>. To get the expected result, 0.43·2<sup>−n</sup> needs to be larger than 1/2 ulp, i.e. 2<sup>−n−2</sup> ⩾ 2<sup>q−p−1</sup>, i.e. n ⩽ p−q−1.

Since q = ⌈log2(n)⌉, the condition is n + ⌈log2(n)⌉ ⩽ p − 1.

But since ⌈log2(n)⌉ is small compared to n, the maximum value of n will be of the order of p, so that one gets an *approximate* condition by replacing ⌈log2(n)⌉ by ⌈log2(p)⌉, i.e. n ⩽ p − ⌈log2(p)⌉ − 1.

Here's a C program using [GNU MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/) to find the first value of n that fails, for each precision p:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpfr.h>

static void test (long p)
{
  mpfr_t x;

  mpfr_init2 (x, p);
  for (long n = 1; ; n++)
    {
      /* i = 2^n + 1 */
      mpfr_set_ui_2exp (x, 1, n, MPFR_RNDN);
      mpfr_add_ui (x, x, 1, MPFR_RNDN);
      mpfr_log2 (x, x, MPFR_RNDN);
      mpfr_ceil (x, x);
      long r = mpfr_get_si (x, MPFR_RNDN);
      if (r != n + 1)
        {
          printf ("p = %ld, fail for n = %ld\n", p, n);
          break;
        }
    }
  mpfr_clear (x);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  long p, pmax;

  if (argc != 2)
    exit (1);
  pmax = strtol (argv[1], NULL, 0);
  for (p = 2; p <= pmax; p++)
    test (p);

  return 0;
}
```

With the argument 64, one gets:

```
p = 2, fail for n = 2
p = 3, fail for n = 3
p = 4, fail for n = 4
p = 5, fail for n = 4
p = 6, fail for n = 5
p = 7, fail for n = 6
p = 8, fail for n = 7
p = 9, fail for n = 8
p = 10, fail for n = 8
p = 11, fail for n = 9
p = 12, fail for n = 10
p = 13, fail for n = 11
p = 14, fail for n = 12
p = 15, fail for n = 13
p = 16, fail for n = 14
p = 17, fail for n = 15
p = 18, fail for n = 16
p = 19, fail for n = 16
p = 20, fail for n = 17
p = 21, fail for n = 18
p = 22, fail for n = 19
p = 23, fail for n = 20
p = 24, fail for n = 21
p = 25, fail for n = 22
p = 26, fail for n = 23
p = 27, fail for n = 24
p = 28, fail for n = 25
p = 29, fail for n = 26
p = 30, fail for n = 27
p = 31, fail for n = 28
p = 32, fail for n = 29
p = 33, fail for n = 30
p = 34, fail for n = 31
p = 35, fail for n = 32
p = 36, fail for n = 32
p = 37, fail for n = 33
p = 38, fail for n = 34
p = 39, fail for n = 35
p = 40, fail for n = 36
p = 41, fail for n = 37
p = 42, fail for n = 38
p = 43, fail for n = 39
p = 44, fail for n = 40
p = 45, fail for n = 41
p = 46, fail for n = 42
p = 47, fail for n = 43
p = 48, fail for n = 44
p = 49, fail for n = 45
p = 50, fail for n = 46
p = 51, fail for n = 47
p = 52, fail for n = 48
p = 53, fail for n = 49
p = 54, fail for n = 50
p = 55, fail for n = 51
p = 56, fail for n = 52
p = 57, fail for n = 53
p = 58, fail for n = 54
p = 59, fail for n = 55
p = 60, fail for n = 56
p = 61, fail for n = 57
p = 62, fail for n = 58
p = 63, fail for n = 59
p = 64, fail for n = 60
```

**EDIT:** So, for double precision (p = 53), if log2 is correctly rounded (or at least, has a good accuracy), the smallest failing integer is 2<sup>49</sup> + 1.

Comment: Thanks for including the example code! I'm not very familiar with MPFR's interface, though— just for the sake of canonicalizing the answer, what is the *lowest* failing integer when a [`double`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#:~:text=Floating%20point%20numbers%20are%20usually%20implemented%20using%20double%20in%20C) is being \(ab\)used for this operation? Is it `2**49 + 1`?

Comment: I ask because Google suggests a double has a 52-bit mantissa, but the output you posted says `p = 52, fail for n = 48` and `i = 2^n + 1`, **but** `test(2**(n:=48) + 1)` succeeds on my machine.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I've just edited my answer: in double precision (p = 53), if log2 is correctly rounded (or at least, has a good accuracy), the smallest failing integer is indeed `2**49 + 1` (if log2 has a bad accuracy, this case might succeed and/or you may have smaller integers that fail; this depends on the implementation). The precision is 53, but only 52 bits are stored since the first bit is always 1 ("implicit bit" rule).